# Why is my collision detection not accurate?

Tags: c++, collision-detection

After trying and trying, I still cannot understand why the leg of character exceeds the wall but no clipping issue when I hit the wall from below. How should I fix it to make him stand still on the wall?

[image: http://i453.photobucket.com/albums/qq253/ulti-killer/13-5.png~original]

From collideWithBox() function below, it shows that `playerDest.Y = boxDest.Y - boxDest.height;` will get the position the character should standstill on the wall. Theoretically, the clipping effect won't be happen as the character hit the box from below works with the equation `playerDest.Y = boxDest.Y + boxDest.height;`.

[image: http://i453.photobucket.com/albums/qq253/ulti-killer/14.png~original]

```
void collideWithBox()
{
    if ( spriteCollide(playerDest, boxDest) && keyArr[VK_UP])
        //playerDest.Y += 50;
        playerDest.Y = boxDest.Y + boxDest.height;
    else if ( spriteCollide(playerDest, boxDest) && !keyArr[VK_UP])
        playerDest.Y = boxDest.Y - boxDest.height;
}



void initPlayer()
{
    //  Create texture.
    hr = D3DXCreateTextureFromFileEx(d3dDevice, "player.png", 169, 44, 
        D3DX_DEFAULT, NULL, D3DFMT_A8R8G8B8, D3DPOOL_MANAGED, 
        D3DX_DEFAULT, D3DX_DEFAULT, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(255, 255, 255), 
        NULL, NULL, &player);

    playerRect.left = playerRect.top = 0;
    playerRect.right = 29; 
    playerRect.bottom = 36;

    playerDest.X  = 0; 
    playerDest.Y  = 564;

    playerDest.length = playerRect.right - playerRect.left;
    playerDest.height = playerRect.bottom - playerRect.top;
}

void initBox()
{
    hr = D3DXCreateTextureFromFileEx(d3dDevice, "brock.png", 330, 132, 
        D3DX_DEFAULT, NULL, D3DFMT_A8R8G8B8, D3DPOOL_MANAGED, 
        D3DX_DEFAULT, D3DX_DEFAULT, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(255, 255, 255), 
        NULL, NULL, &box);

    boxRect.left = 33;
    boxRect.top = 0;
    boxRect.right = 63; 
    boxRect.bottom = 30;

    boxDest.X = boxDest.Y = 300;

    boxDest.length = boxRect.right - boxRect.left;
    boxDest.height = boxRect.bottom - boxRect.top;
}

bool spriteCollide(Entity player, Entity target)
{
    float left1, left2;
    float right1, right2;
    float top1, top2;
    float bottom1, bottom2;

    left1 = player.X;
    left2 = target.X;
    right1 = player.X + player.length;
    right2 = target.X + target.length;

    top1 = player.Y;
    top2 = target.Y;

    bottom1 = player.Y + player.height;
    bottom2 = target.Y + target.height;

    if (bottom1 < top2) return false;
    if (top1 > bottom2) return false;

    if (right1 < left2) return false;
    if (left1 > right2) return false;

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Just something to note: You are passing by value into spriteCollide(). This will do unnecessary copying. You probably don't want that.

Comment: Hey optimisez. This is pretty close to a code dump question. Can you further describe the problem (perhaps with images?) and the debugging steps you've already taken?

Comment: I think what he mean is, how to prevent the character from "going down" the floor below him.
It's like, the floor's top position is Y 500, character's bottom position is Y 505 when he jumped and land on the floor. He wants it to be landing perfectly at Y 500

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`playerDest.Y = boxDest.Y - boxDest.height`

should be

`playerDest.Y = boxDest.Y - playerDest.height`